# flutter with vs code

Tags: flutter, dart

when  I click run in vs code it show this message  :"Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components.s code with flutter" . please give me soloution to this problem 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/386uY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rWxO.jpg)

Comment: "[...] please run 'flutter doctor' [...]"

Comment: Did you run 'flutter doctor' though?

Comment: Could you run flutter doctor and show the output you get? Also are you trying to run it on a physical device or an emulator? Try running the flutter run command from the integrated terminal in vs code using ctrl+shift+tab key and make sure you have a device connected which shows in the bottom left of your vs code screen.

Comment: flutter doctor run simply but when I run from vs code with genymotion . it show msg "Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components.s code with flutter"

Comment: I putted some images in description you can look it then tell me what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

In general, it looks like you didn't create an iOS simulator or Android emulator to run your app.

Use the AVD Manager from within Android Studio to create an Android virtual device or use Xcode on macOS to create an iOS simulator and then try again!

Please also share your `flutter doctor -v` result here so we can have a look at the problem exactly.

Comment: I putted some images in description you can see itthen tel me wath is the problem . I use vs code not android studio .